# Getting the contents of a file in Visual Studio without opening the file from an extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to read the contents of a file in a Visual Studio extension.  The following code works, but forces me to open the file, if it isn't (otherwise it crashes):

```
textDocument = (TextDocument)projectItem.Document.Object("TextDocument");    
EditPoint editPoint = textDocument.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
string text =  editPoint.GetText(textDocument.EndPoint);
```

I can get the path of the project, so I suppose I could make an educated guess as to the location of the project item.  However, ideally I'd like to either get the file contents without opening it; or, alternatively, get the path to the project item (then I could just use System.IO to access the file contents).

I've looked, but don't seem to be able to find any mention of either of these.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: You need to shomehow read the file, which requires reading the bytes from disk. The definition of opening is very vague in this question, is reading bytes from disk considering opening a file?

Comment: I suppose the OP means that opening the file in Visual Studio should be prevented. @GertjanBrouwer.

Comment: Why don't you use `Application.StartupPath` to get the path to the debug folder, then you can navigate back or forth the required number of times from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path from a `ProjectItem` by reading its properties.

```
var path = YourProjectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString()
```

After you have the `path` you can read its content with `System.IO`.

```cs
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

If the file is somewhat larger and you are getting troubles with the current code due to size, you should take a look at the [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible for extensions but you could probably  use [System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8), like this:

```
using System.IO;

string filePath = @"C:\Whatever\YourFileName.txt";
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

You could also use [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```
using System.IO;

string filePath = @"C:\Whatever\YourFileName.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    fileText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

**EDIT:**

I think I understand you better now.

The only way to "get the file contents without opening it" would be if the extension were to give you that data actively, but I can safely assume it doesn't.

When reading a file, you should already know where the file is (if you don't know then either you're not intended to access that file or you just haven't looked long enough).

I'd try searching the SDK files manually (Or with a file crawler).

Comment: Yes, but how do I get 'Whatever' from the SDK?

Comment: I may have understood you wrong. Are you making an extension for visual basic that needs to read a file, or are you trying to read a file that belongs to an extension for visual studio?